# Get total of value in EditText in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I want to create demo app that calculate prize of content in listview.
User can set quantity in Edittext, from that quantity i want auto sum of all imtems.
Currently i have use **setOnFocusChangeListener** on Edittext.. but i am failed to get tatal.
Please see image...
[image]

Any suggestion ?

Thanks..

Comment: Share the code you have so far.

Comment: No reason for code, its purely theoretical in terms of design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `setOnFocusChangeListener` use for each EditText

```
addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            totalTextView.setText(getSumOfAll());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On the `EditText`, you can add a `TextWatcher` with `addTextChangedListener(...)`.

This `TextWatcher` will change the underlining data and call `onDataChanged()` on the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Use ListViews `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt(i)` to get your EditTexts then `getText()` and 
summarize them.

```
     int count = listviewview.getChildCount();
     int sum=0;
        for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {

            EditText t = (EditText)((YourLayout)view.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(1); //1 will get your EditText from the Layout of the List Item because you have 3 children there.
            sum+=Integer.parseInt(t.getText());

        }
return sum*yourprice;
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since your rows ideally are fixed (or not) either or it does not matter. All you need to do is iterate through each item in your ListView's Adapter and then grab the text from each of them  and then extract your data. Then keep track of it, and handle it however you wish to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set TextWatcher on each textview, and on text changed method, get string from each edit text, parse value to integer, and add to sum.